# What is the difference between Shamed and Ashamed?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between Shamed and Ashamed ?

Answer (score 3):

*Shamed* is the result of somebody's or something's actions or words. *I was shamed* is almost always a passive, implying "somebody or something shamed me". It is a statement about a social interaction and its consequences, and not directly about feelings (though they may follow as a consequence).

*Ashamed* is an adjective, referring to one's feelings. This may result from being *shamed* (by somebody), but may be a purely internal reaction to what happens.

So, suppose I have told a lie.

If somebody noticed that lie, and tells everybody that I have lied, I am shamed by them. I might feel ashamed, but I might have different feelings about it. For example, if I feel my lie was justified, I might reject that (public) shaming.

If somebody tells me about an awful consequence of that lie, without knowing that I told the lie, I might feel ashamed.